# Getting rollback error in JPA when deploying to smartfox

Tags: java, jpa, smartfoxserver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JPA RollbackException but not in unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694036/jpa-rollbackexception-but-not-in-unit-test)

I have an issue that is not present when running a unit test using JPA 2.0, but if I try to use this functionality within a handler I get an exception.

ie this works fine - I can verify the change in the database

```
    LevelDAO dao = new LevelDAO();
    List levels = dao.findAll();
    int i = levels.size();
    Level l = (Level) levels.get(i-1);
    l.setName("bla");
    EntityManagerHelper.beginTransaction();
    dao.update(l);
    EntityManagerHelper.commit();
```

When I try to deploy this to a handler (Smartfox Extension) I receive a rollback exception:

save successful <-- (i receive this msg in both cases)

However for my Smartfox deployment...

ie. MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException : column 'levelid' cannot be null
Query: UpdateObjectQuery(com.abc.model.Layer@10ae6fc)

Which is run from

```
public class SetModelHandler extends BaseClientRequestHandler

@Override
public void handleClientRequest(User sender, ISFSObject params)
```

The database change doesnt happen. I'm able to read the base fine from within this handler. Anyone have any ideas about how to pursue this?

Ta,